# Grab all text inside a container using Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I hope someone could help me out on this one. Basically i have this website that has a lot of dialog boxes. These dialog boxes are changed dynamically and they are not any means static content. My task is to grab all the text inside the dialog box, they might be a drop down menu (simple `SELECT` and `OPTION`) or it might contain radio button with text beside it, or even checkbox with text beside it etc.. But i need to find a way to GRAB everything inside a container id.

For example: www.facebook.com

The Notification box i only want the text inside that container how would i go about?
It's class id is 
`"uiScrollableArea fade uiScrollableAreaWithShadow contentAfter contentBefore"`
Lets assume for our example the class id is `uiScrollableAreaWithShadow`.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to scrape everything off large sites like facebook & gmail is really not recommended & prone to fail since they are changing all the time, you're better off using the available APIs

Comment: again that was an example.. the web interface im working with is a lot smaller i had nothing else to show an example with

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by getting the WebElement or Select Object Text

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html